# Showing subspace is not closed under multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have a function $f(x^2) = f(x)^2$ and its asking to show if its a subspace of $V$, where $V$ is the real vector space of all functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I know that you have to show closure under addition and multiplication, however I'm a bit confused on this:

$(cf)(x^2) = cf(x^2)$ but does $cf(x^2) = (cf(x))^2$ or does it mean that $cf(x^2) = cf(x)^2$ based on the function defined by the question above. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It should be $cf(x^2) = c(f(x)^2)$.

Comment: That's what I though to but for some reason the book claims that it doesn't close under multiplication so therefore its not a vector space. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? How is this not a subspace?

Comment: In general, $x^2 + y^2 \neq (x+y)^2$.

Comment: Sorry typo in my last post. It claims that it doesn't close under multiplication. How is that so?

Comment: Oh I get what you mean; I was a little confused. $(cf)(x^2) = c^2f(x)^2$, where $cf$ is the vector $f$ multiplied by scalar $c$. But it is also not closed under addition.

Comment: I'm jumbled up. How did you get that? Sorry I keep pestering I just really want to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

It is not closed under multiplication. The claim you have to prove is that for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ you have that

$$(cf)(x^2) = ((cf)(x))^2.$$

This is not true. Take $c = 2$. Then

$$(2f)(x^2) = 2f(x^2) \text{ and } ((2f)(x))^2 = 4(f(x))^2 \neq 2(f(x))^2.$$

Comment: OMG Thank you! That is all I wanted to know. That totally clarified the question.

Comment: @user184679 Glad to help. Consider upvoting and accepting.